# Duplicate data is getting updated ob table

Tags: php, mysql, drupal

I am looking to update one of the table. After I update, all the duplicate data is getting inserted again. Especially, the cloneSQL part of the code. I tried using DISTINCT, NOT EXISTS but no luck.

```
if(DB_num_rows($checkResult) > 0){
                $cloneSQL = "UPDATE DISTINCT pricematrixdiscount SET 
                            discount='" . $vals[3] . "'
                            WHERE debtorno='" . $_POST['cloneTo'] . "', 
                            product_line='" . $vals[1] . "', 
                            salestype='" . $vals[2] . "' ";
            }
             else {
                $cloneSQL = "INSERT into pricematrixdiscount
                                (debtorno,
                                product_line,
                                salestype,
                                discount) VALUES
                                ('" . $_POST['cloneTo'] . "',
                                '" . $vals[1] . "', 
                                '" . $vals[2] . "',
                                '" . $vals[3] . "')";
```

How can I insert only distinct values on the pricematricdiscount table without the duplicates being inserted?

Comment: My first guess would be to check the logic behind DB_num_rows and whatever is generating $checkResult (since those two things control insert vs update). It would also help if you included the schema for your table as well as an example of what the "duplicates" look like.

Comment: Logic behind DB_num_rows '$checkSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM pricematrixdiscount
       WHERE debtorno='" . $_POST['cloneTo'] . "' 
       AND product_line='" . $vals[1] . "' 
       AND salestype='" . $vals[2] . "'";
   $checkResult = DB_query($checkSQL);'

Comment: Wasn't DB_num_rows deprecated like a decade ago?